# global variable is not shared between thread and MQTT receive python

Tags: python, global-variables, global

Mainthread:

```
client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(Broker, 1883, 60)
client.on_log = on_log
client.loop_start()

global alarm
alarm = True

while True:        
    try:
        if alarm == True:
        ...
```

and in function have change variable:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    message = str(msg.payload)
    if message.lower() == 'alarm off': alarm = False
    elif message.lower() == 'alarm on': alarm = True
```

It works like separate variable in function and Mainthread i can't found why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The var should be flagged as global in the on_message function not where you have it.

```
client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(Broker, 1883, 60)
client.on_log = on_log
client.loop_start()

alarm = True

while True:        
    try:
        if alarm == True:
        ...
```

and

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    global alearm
    message = str(msg.payload)
    if message.lower() == 'alarm off': alarm = False
    elif message.lower() == 'alarm on': alarm = True
```

Comment: One more question is it some another options to make variable global because this way set variable as global every time when is called this function. Just for better looking code. Thanks

Comment: No, it just tells the runtime to use the global version rather than create a new local variable for each invocation of the `on_message` function